# Exporting integers as an image in Java

Tags: java

How can I export an array of three colour values (0-255), (0-255), (0-255) as an image in Java? I have a 3-D array where the first the first two dimensions define the pixel and the third dimension, containing three elements, has the three RGB values.

Comment: [Official tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/saveimage.html) or anything else on the [first page of Google results for "java save image"](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+save+image).

Comment: If I have a hypothetical 800x800 array of colour values that I want to export as a png file of the above resolution, how exactly would I do that?

Comment: I just edited my post, but if you want to simply save an image file this is not the answer, and you should not do it with an array,

Answer (score 0):

Try String 2D array and parse it later back to a int,
E.g. if your pixel '0,0' is the color '25,25,25'
*pixel [0] [0] = "25,25,25"*
and then use *String.split(",")* to split the String into rr,gg,bb

Comment: Ok let's say I had a colour value of [25,25,25]. How would I represent that as a single integer? Or is there a way of exporting a colour in that format?